# In more canonical OO Python situations, what is the rule of thumb for default access modifiers?

Tags: design-patterns, python, programming-languages, object-oriented-design, encapsulation

Generally speaking in canonical OOP situations, the rule of thumb is to write your classes with the least access as necessary. i.e. only make public only what is necessary, make protected only what is necessary, etc etc. (There are exceptions and what I describe does not always apply. FWIW, I find the idea of "least access as necessary" to be useful in more canonical OO C++/Java situations.)

However in Python, you don't have strict access modifiers like `public`, `protected`, `private`, etc. Python has pseudo `protected` and pseudo `private` in the form of single `_` and double `__` underscores for your object fields and methods.

**In more "canonical OO"[1] Python situations, what is the rule of thumb for default access modifiers?**

Is the rule of thumb to restrict more (like in C++/Java) and qualify all fields/methods with `__` until there is a requirement/design/API need to make it `public` or `protected`?

Or is the rule of thumb to start with all your python fields/methods as `public` and restrict them as needed?

I have seen some who default to `protected` with `_` and use `pylint` to catch breaking encapsulation. I can also see others who would default to `private`. And I'm sure there are still others who default to `public`.

[1]
I use the term "canonical OO" to refers to more of what I would call textbook OO programming theory/situations. In my experience real programming often differs from textbook OO or canonical OO programming theory.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to word "only make public only what is necessary, make protected only what is necessary" but I wanted to get this question out there.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a canonical answer, but as a rule of thumb, I prefix every attribute by an underscore, and I expose them using [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) if necessary. I also believe it's a bit misleading to talk about `protected` and `private` in Python's context because I don't think it relates very well to the same concept in, say, Java.

Comment: Have you read [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)? The naming section covers all of this. Also we're all consenting adults here and everything is public really (`foo.foo`, `foo._bar` and `foo.__Foo_baz`).

Comment: @VincentSavard hopefully not in violation of *"For simple public data attributes, it is best to expose just the attribute name, without complicated accessor/mutator methods"*!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I still prefer to use a property, since it has the side effect of disallowing setting the attribute unless explicitly specified. I don't consider properties "complicated accessor/mutator methods".

Comment: @VincentSavard and jonrsharpe instead of offering [partial answers in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292140), [could you please submit an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25159) The links I provided talk about how Answers are preferred on all stackexchange websites.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith You asked for a canonical answer. I can only provide an answer based on my own experience, and as you surely know, if this is what you're actually looking for, your question is primarily opinion-based and should be closed.

Comment: -1. This question has been asked a dozen times before. Python doesn't have access modifiers and you shouldn't try to emulate them

Comment: @MilesRout your answer is completely nonconstructive and unhelpful. you say that this question has been asked a dozen times but you provide zero links to the supposed "duplicate questions". If you were being constructive/helpful you would have posted the dozen links. If you were being constructive you would additionally vote to close this question as a duplicate (and carefully chosen the best question of the dozen as the one that this one duplicates).

Comment: @MilesRout additionaly may I remind you: ["There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and ["duplication is not necessarily bad. Quite the contrary — some duplication is desirable. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @MilesRout I spent a while searching for this question and was unable to find any *good* questions on stackexchange and so if you really do have a dozen links then please do share. When I did my searching, I was expecting to find questions with at least 300+ upvotes but instead I didn't find any good questions on stackoverflow or stackexchange.

Comment: There are lots of questions like 'why doesn't Python have access modifiers', 'what does __attr mean in Python?', 'what is the difference between _attr and __attr in Python?', 'how do I make a method private in Python?', etc.

Answer (score 5):

First of all the double underscore (sometimes called *dunder*) is not meant to be private, but rather a name mangling strategy to avoid certain conflicts. Check [this talk of Raymond Hettinger](https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg?t=37m16s) (one of the Python core developers... and the the whole talk is totally worth the time). I personally have never ever needed the dunder/name mangling.

So, the question is rather about when to "protect" by using one underscore, and when not to. My rule of thumb for this is: keep things as private and simple as possible.

Say you have a `Stone` class with for the moment only attributes for material and weight. A recipe could go like this:

1. Default to underscoring everything: `_weight` and `_material`
2. Think veeery carefully about the class API and answer this question: **what members are to be exposed?**. Then convert these members to public by removing the underscore. Let's say `_weight` gets converted to `weight`
3. As time goes by, you might need to convert a you-shouldn't-care member, into a full public member. No shame about it, just remove the underscore and refactor the class code to match the new name, e.g. `_material` > `material`. Don't create a `@property` to access the previous attribute, it is just more complex.
4. Again, as time goes by, it can be that one of the attributes gets dependent on another, let's say that `weight` becomes dependent on `volume` and `density`, but worry not! now it is time to convert the `weight` attribute into a `@property` and keep a single source of truth without breaking existing code.